# Can not get Joomla! JText to output translation

Tags: joomla, plugins, translation

Im writing an Joomla plugin but can not get the JText to output the right translation.

Seems somehow that the *.ini will not load.

in my configurationfile. (.xml):

            language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_content_rsstotable.ini

in the .ini file:

TECH_HOME=Technical homepage
GUIDEDOC=Guide document

Answer (score 2):

Language files for plugins are not loaded automatically. To load it, you have to use

```
JPlugin::loadLanguage('plg_content_rsstotable', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
```